# I see only 511mb volume from another disk with linux

Tags: grub2, disk

I installed new system on my ssd and i plug second disk with this same linux ubuntu to my PC and i cant see anything beyond folder grub but i must copy files from this second disk. How i can do that?

I cant mount or i dont know how. When I use: `sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /home
 i get

```
   wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb2,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

Comment: have you mounted your other disk , so you can `rsync` or copy the files ?

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu installer normally uses extended partitions so the filesystem is likely to be on the device sdb5.

You can get a list of all the block devices connected to your system with the command lsblk

The install uses LVM to manage the disks, you will need to start up the LVM subsystem. To do this do the following:

Find LVM volume groups, in this example one called storage with a volume called working inside.

```
sudo vgscan
Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
Found volume group "storage" using metadata type lvm2
```

Next start the volume group up

```
sudo vgchange -a y storage
1 logical volume(s) in volume group "storage" now active
```

List the logical volumes within the new volume group

```
sudo lvs storage
LV      VG      Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
working storage -wi-ao---- 80.00g
```

Finally mount the volume:

```
sudo mount /dev/storage/working /mountpoint
```

Note if you are using a GUI desktop then the devices might appear as storage devices after you have started the LVM volume group up.

Comment: Okay you have right its sdb5 but now when i tried to  mount i got "mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'"

Comment: Please can you edit the question to include the information about in being on LVM